# Angular: route param at start

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to make a route as http://localhost:4200/1234/page1/page/2/page3 and so on.

but in above url 123 (id) is optional, so below url is also valid
http://localhost:4200/page1/page/2/page3

I tried to as handle it for page 1 component as

```
  const routes: Routes = [
      { path: ':id/page1', pathMatch: 'full', component: Page1Component },
      { path: 'page1', pathMatch: 'full', component: Page1Component }
    ];
```

for I have to define 2 routes here, similarly if I go for other component routes, again I need to give 2 routes for each component.

So is there a smart way to handle this.?

Comment: The smart way would be not to start your routes with a param ... You should instead give it a specific URL so that it does not collude with other routes. Besides, your ID param isn't optional, it's mandatory : it's your bad routing design that makes it optional. Finally, [tell us what issue you're facing instead of asking for help on a solution that you think is the right one](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I agree to you, routes shouldn't go this way but sometimes business side wins over technical side.

Comment: That's not an excuse and it's mostly false. And I would like to hear the business rule that forces you to do something like that, because at the top of my head, I can count at least 3 different ways of having the same result with better practices.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like it. It was good enough. You need to define 2 paths for 2 possible way of accessing from the route.

Source: [Angular Router Series: Secondary Outlets Primer](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-router-series-secondary-outlets-primer-139206595e2), [The Powerful URL Matching Engine of Angular Router](https://vsavkin.com/the-powerful-url-matching-engine-of-angular-router-775dad593b03)

---

Update:

Alternatively, one of the better options which I can think is using [`NavigationExtras#state`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state)

which require extra `import { NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';` on sender component and:

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = { state: { id: this.datatobepassed } };
this.router.navigate(['test'], navigationExtras);
```

to send the data.

And on the receiver component:

```
const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
const state = navigation.extras.state as {id: number};
this.example = state.id;
```

to receive the data.

See the following [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgbckm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest-navigation%2Ftest-navigation.component.ts)

Comment: Indeed, now it's an answer :) but I'm keeping my downvote, as I strongly disagree with you : the issue originates from a bad design by the OP ; giving him a workaround instead of correcting his mistakes is basically encouraging bad practices.

Comment: It's okay at least if someone were able to be on track with this it was good enough.